# issue | JQuery slide forces my page to scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my slide HTML :

```
<div class="slide_container">
        <div class="one_slide">
            <a href="#"><img alt="slide_img" class="slide_img img-responsive" src="images/slide2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="one_slide">
            <a href="#"><img alt="slide_img" class="slide_img img-responsive" src="images/slide3.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="one_slide">
                <a href="#"><img alt="slide_img" class="slide_img img-responsive" src="images/slide4.jpg"></a>
        </div>

</div>
```

And the JQuery :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('old_active');
    if($('.old_active').is(':last-child')){
      $('.one_slide').first().addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $('.old_active').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.old_active').removeClass('old_active');
    $('.one_slide').fadeOut(500);
    $('.active').fadeIn(500);
},5000);
```

This is my JQuery slide, the problem with it is when the image change it's forcing my page to scroll to the top and i don't like this, i searched for the same issue but no result .

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the 'href="#"', this is responsible for the upscrolling!

Comment: i deleted the entire `a` element but it still same issue

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behavior you descriped. I added the class "active" to the first `<div class="one_slide">` and then it worked fine. (I was using Opera 43 (latest) and jQuery 3.1.1).

Comment: I tried it on Firefox it's working fine, this problem is just with Chrome i dont know why.

Comment: Strange, because Opera and Chrome share the same codebase (Webkit)... try to code the things you want in another way and see if you can work around this...